# GitHub Actions: `git push` to CodeCommit fails after rebase

Tags: git, github-actions, aws-codecommit

I am currently working on a GitHub Action that saves my repository to AWS CodeCommit. It looks like this:

```yaml
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: "checkout"
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: "add aws codecommit remote"
        run: ...

      - name: "push repository to aws codecommit"
        run: |
          git fetch --tags
          git fetch --all
          git push aws --force --all
          git push aws --tags
```

This action works well, but you can break it by doing the following:

- Checkout feature/a
- Commit and push something
- Checkout feature/b (from feature/a)
- Commit and push something
- Checkout master
- Commit and push some things
- Checkout feature/b
- Rebase to master
- Push again

Now I get the following error:

```
error: remote unpack failed: Unknown commit XXXX
To https://git-codecommit.my-region-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/***
 ! [remote rejected] feature/b -> feature/b (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git-codecommit.my-region-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/***'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Funnily, it works if I perform the exact same steps on my local machine. I have checked many possible solutions to these problems, but they all suggest a force push or permission problems, which just isn't the case. I tried these solutions anyway, but nothing worked.

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Cheers and thank you in advance!

Comment: When using the action/checkout, you need to add the `fetch-depth:0` variable if you wish to fetch all history: [reference](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches).

Comment: Damn, it was so simple! Thank you so much @GuiFalourd. If you post this as your answer I will mark it as correct :)

Comment: Thanks :) I experienced something similar recently. Depending on what you want to do, sometimes you even need to add a PAT because the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't have all permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `action/checkout`, you need to add the `fetch-depth:0` variable if you wish to fetch all history: [reference](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches).

```
    steps:
      - name: "checkout"
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
          with:
           fetch-depth: 0
```